# Karliah not showing up at the Ragged Flagon after Hard Answers

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have completed the mission "Hard Answers for the Thieves Guild" story line but I think there might be a glitch. I've seen posts all over the internet with just about the same exact problem. She told me to meet her at the Ragged Flagon but she's not there, she's still at the Snow Veil Sanctum. When I went there she was glitched at the exit, I got her un-glitched and it did nothing! I play on the console (Xbox 360) so I cant break the quest.

Comment: Please try to write descriptive titles for your questions.

Comment: Sorry new to the site just want any possible answers

Comment: Since you are on a console it is mostly not possible to fix anything due to the lack of the console, so better off reloading an older save right away and save the time.

Comment: @user28015 It's interesting how you can't use the console while you are on a... console! (Sorry, bad word play here).

Comment: Alright thanks for telling me user28015 But I cant go back to a previous save, So now I guess I cant complete the Thieves Guild Storyline...Crap